# CFScript Evaluate() throws error in loop

Tags: coldfusion

I'm attempting to dump a bunch of `get` functions into a spreadsheet using `cfspreadsheet` - instead of passing each individual function, I've decided to create a list and loop through it. I think I am using `Evaluate()` incorrectly here, but I'm not sure what the best way to accomplish this is. Any suggestions/optimizations would be appreciated, as my Cold-Fu isn't that great.

Error thrown is `Variable GETFIELDS is undefined.`

```
<cfset var fields = "Function1,Function2" />
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="#strDestinationPath#information.xls" name="xlsInfo" headerrow="1" />
<cfset var row = xlsData.rowcount + 1 />
<cfset var count = 1 />
<cfloop list="fields" index="f" delimiters=",">
   <cfscript>
    SpreadsheetSetCellValue(xlsInfo,Evaluate('get' & f & '()'),row,count);
    count++;
   </cfscript>  
</cfloop>   
<cfspreadsheet action="write" overwrite="true" filename="#strDestinationPath#information.xls" name="xlsInformation" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cfloop` expects a [list of items](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-71a7.html) as an argument.

Try changing from

```
<cfloop list="fields" index="f" delimiters=",">
```

to

```
<cfloop list="#fields#" index="f" delimiters=",">
```

or to

```
<cfloop list="Function1,Function2" index="f" delimiters=",">
```

Comment: I can't test that right now, but I'm going to feel like an idiot if I missed that, haha! Will report back soon.

Comment: I don't know how many times I've made that mistake myself. =)

Comment: *facepalm* too much coding today.